# Chaining Iterators inplace

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to extend an iterator while iterating over it.

I want to iterate over request and in case they timeout, I want to split the request and add them to the running loop.

Something like this:

```py
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
it = iter(l)
for e in it:
  try: 
    request(e)
  except Exception:
    it.append(split_request(e))
```

But `append` does not work and `itertools.chain` returns a new iterator instead of changing the iterator inplace.

Comment: What does `split_request(e)` do with the `int` object `e`?

Comment: This question needs to be better explained. it's by no means clear what you are asking here. it's rarely helpful just to say something "does not work." That's not how you'd get your car fixed! You mention `itertools.chain` but don't explain how you tried to use it, or why. It's rarely a good idea to iterate over something that's changing with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `while` loop. Inside that, iterate over the list and accumulate a list of the failed entries. When that list is empty the `while` loop can terminate. Something like:

```
while l:
    failures = []
    for e in l:
        try:
            request(e)
        except Exception:
            failures.append(split_request(e))
    l = failures
```

should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need a while loop and handle indexing and iterating yourself

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
i = 0
while i < len(l):
  try: 
    request(l[i])
    i += 1
  except Exception:
    l[i] = split_request(l[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code tries each of the list twice and outputs a dictionary with values that resulted in errors and number of attempts. You could make `errors` a list and stop appending if `len(errors)` is too big.

```
import itertools
l = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 'a', 2]
it = iter(l)
errors = {}
for e in itertools.chain(it, errors):
    try:
        print('e =', e, ' 1/e = ', end=' ')
        print(1/e)                              <---- May Fail 
    except Exception:
        errors[e] = errors.get(e, 0) + 1
        print('Error')

print('errors', errors)
```

O/P

```
e = -2  1/e =  -0.5
e = -1  1/e =  -1.0
e = 0  1/e =  Error
e = 1  1/e =  1.0
e = a  1/e =  Error
e = 2  1/e =  0.5
e = 0  1/e =  Error
e = a  1/e =  Error
>>> print('errors', errors)
errors {0: 2, 'a': 2}
```